# Make shapefile from raster-bounds in Python

Tags: python, raster, shapefile, shapely, rasterio

I have a raster that I opened with `rasterio`. When I do `raster.bounds` I get 
`BoundingBox(left=399960.0, bottom=-3309780.0, right=609780.0, top=-3099960.0)`.
My question is now, if there is any simple way to make a shapefile of it?

Comment: the thing is I have a raster with a bounding box. I don't want to create a bounding box using coordinates

Comment: Please don't comment on your own question. Instead, [Edit] the Question to contain this information. One in mind that raster boundaries are sometimes computed from center-center of the corner pixels, so your polygon may be a half-pixel too small in each corner.

Comment: thank you very much for the advices:)!

Answer (score 26):

With [shapely box](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.geometry.box) and [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/)

```
import rasterio as rio
ra = rio.open("raster.tif")
bounds  = ra.bounds
```

Convert bounds to shapely geometry

```
from shapely.geometry import box
geom = box(*bounds)
print(geom.wkt)
POLYGON ((205625.4144070312 88411.04799999669, 205625.4144070312 90534.35044407193, 202086.5770002506 90534.35044407193, 202086.5770002506 88411.04799999669, 205625.4144070312 88411.04799999669))
```

Create a shapefile with GeoPandas

```
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"id":1,"geometry":[geom]})
df.to_file("boundary.shp")
```

In one line:

```
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"id":1,"geometry":[box(*bounds)]})
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For scripting, other answers does the job. If you need generating shp from command line, I would recommand to use rasterio command line utility `rio` with

```bsh
rio bounds /tmp/RGBA.byte.tif > tmp.geojson
ogr2ogr RGBA.shp tmp.geojson
rm tmp.geojson
```

You could also use `gdaltindex` e.g

```bsh
gdaltindex RGBA.shp RGBA.byte.tif
```

Comment: gdaltindex is nice！

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using `shapely` and `fiona` that takes into account the spatial reference of the raster and makes sure the new shapefile has it:

```py
# imports
from shapely.geometry import box, mapping
import fiona
import rasterio

# create a Polygon from the raster bounds
bbox = box(*raster.bounds)

# create a schema with no properties
schema = {'geometry': 'Polygon', 'properties': {}}

# create shapefile
with fiona.open('bbox.shp', 'w', driver='ESRI Shapefile',
                crs=raster.crs.to_dict(), schema=schema) as c:
    c.write({'geometry': mapping(bbox), 'properties': {}})
```

Comment: GeoPandas use Fiona

Answer (score 3):

There is also a GDAL program gdaltindex https://gdal.org/programs/gdaltindex.html for this purpose.

> **Description**
>
> This program builds a shapefile with a record for each input raster
>   file, an attribute containing the filename, and a polygon geometry
>   outlining the raster.